# Перечисление профессий - как оформить?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли в данном предложении перечисление профессий оформить через запятую или лучше поставить скобки? 
N.N., председатель группы; N.N., управление производственными процессами всей группы; N.N., управление маркетингом, продажами и продвижение компании на рынке.

Comment: А что означают эти латинские буквы?

Comment: Имя и фамилию.

Comment: Здесь после имя и фамилии идет приложение, которое выделяется запятыми. Но вопрос  в другом. После имя и фамилии неправильно писать место работы специалиста.Как например: N.N., управление производственными процессами всей группы; В этом случае правильно будет написать профессию. Напр: N.N., управляющий маркетингом, продажами и продвижением компании на рынке.

Comment: Да, я об этом думала. Но "управляющий маркетингом" как-то "не звучит". Потому и захотела поставить должность и описание профессии в скобки.

Comment: Однако это правильный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный текст без контекста больше похож не на предложение, а на справочную информацию (например, -- перечень сотрудников и их должностей в документе). В таком случае это, скорее, типографическая проблема, а не грамматическая, и запятая здесь просто отделяет инициалы от должности, а точка с запятой отделяет одну позицию от другой. Это допустимо, так же как, например, допустимо отделить инициалы от должности несколькими пробелами или табуляцией, а позиции -- переносом или вообще оформить в виде таблицы.

Если же это часть предложения (например, "На заседании присутствовали: Иванов. И.И., председатель группы, Петров. П.П., управляющий маркетингом, ..."), то в данном случае указанная профессия -- [обращение](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_180), которое необходимо обособить запятыми (точки с запятой не нужны). Но можно и в скобках поставить, тогда это будет уточняющая информация.

Answer (score 0):

Для удобства чтения лучше скобки или тире.